# Is there a non SDE version for the DisconnectUser (arcpy) function?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy

My work environment consists of multiple file geodatabases, on a number of shared network drives that can be accessed by multiple users at a given time.  When I try to push out updates to feature classes or feature datasets, I get "locked by user" on many occasions.  I do not have SDE so was wondering if there is a way to accomplish a non SDE version of the DisconnectUser function so I can continue my updates.

Comment: Do any of the users require write access?  Never tried this but it seems like you could make them readonly for everyone but you, preventing others from creating lock files.

Comment: @KirkKuykendall They do require write access but they should never at one point be editing the same feature class.  Editing will likely be done in the same feature dataset and file geodatabase  but not the same feature class.

Answer (score 2):

Disconnected editing and replication are irrevocably tied to versioning, but since best practice is avoid accessing file geodatabases over a network, if you're willing to turn things inside-out, you can

- Maintain the master FGDBs locally,
- Have users access a local copy cloned from the master, and
- Notify users or organize some sort of automated pull process* to let users update their local store when an update is available.

PS: After thinking about it a bit, you might be able to use [Subversion](https://subversion.apache.org/) to distribute the changed data to users.  It would be in binary mode, so the data volume might be larger than customary use, but you'll be saving so much on time and network I/O, you might not even notice.

Comment: I have no experience with Subversion so I will probably not use that option.  I may do the "inside-out" approach, my initial concerns would be structuring a process where I can easily access the data they(users) edit and maintain.

Comment: It took me about 20 minutes to become experienced with Subversion.  It's certainly the most stable way to distribute data, and all your users need to learn is "svn update".

Comment: If you're going to do multiuser editing, you're going to need a multiuser editing solution (e.g., workgroup or enterprise geodatabase). Using file geodatabases for this purpose is only going to cause pain.

Comment: I will probably end up researching SQL server express capabilities and implementing multi-User editing functionality that way.  Again, I'm not experienced with enterprise databases so all of this is over my head at this point.